# keycloak , konga and react application authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, keycloak

Hi my current setup is i use keycloak and konga (they are all on oci) for authentication , after logging in to my keycloak login screen it redirects me to my react application.

Now i want to access my access token and all the details i required to create a profile page in my react application, Also with this i also want to create users in my keycloak from my react application.
How can i do all this?

can anyone Please explain or share a complete documentation on this , as i am new to keycloak and doesnt find any good documentation on this :(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.